# Git how to remove old commit from branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have 5 commits, i want to remove the 3rd commit and then merge back with head.

I tried the below but on Gitlab it says "No changes to commit"

First i created a branch from the commit before the 3rd commit.

```
git branch revertimages <2nd commit>
```

Then i merged the commit after the 3rd commit.

```
git fetch origin
git merge <4th commit>
```

But when i attempt a merge request with this new branch revertimages into master it says no changes?

How do i remove the 3rd commit(not permanently) so gitlab will see the changes(removed all 3rd commit code).

Comment: Are you sure that you want to fix commit history in the branch instead `git merge --squash` the entire branch back to `master`?

Comment: So these 5 commits are into master already? Did you already share your current master's state with the origin? If you did then you'd better just commit a revert of the 3rd commit on top of the 5 commits.

Comment: @user892134 Did my answer help you solve your issue? If so, could you accept my answer so others will be able to find the correct answer, please?

Answer (score 3):

When [merging in Git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge), you're not merging an individual commit but the whole branch instead. That means, you're merging all changes from all commits starting with the commit you specified in the `git merge` command all the way back until some common point between the source and the target branch.

Consider the following state:

```
      F---G---H---I  branch A
     /
A---B---C---D        master
```

Now, you want to merge the commit `H` from the branch `A` into the `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
git merge H
```

The result will be:

```
      F---G---H---I  branch A
     /         \
A---B---C---D---J    master
```

That means, in the end, the `master` branch will contain changes from all commits except of `I`.

**If you want to transfer just changes from an individual commit from one branch into another, use [*cherry picking*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)** instead. This way, only the changes in the commit specified in the `git cherry-pick` command are being transferred.

Let's start with the same initial state and cherry-pick commits `G` and `H` into the `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick G
git cherry-pick H
```

The result will look like the following:

```
      F---G---H---I    branch A
     /         
A---B---C---D---G---H  master
```

That means, in the end, the `master` branch will contain all commits except of `F` and `I`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a branch from the latest commit and revert the specific commit that you don't want.

```
git branch revertimages <5th commit>
git revert  --no-commit <commit you want to remove>
```

This will modify the local files as if the commit was removed. Review and commit the changes.

Comment: i get this error when doing git revert "is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed"

Comment: Did you create a new branch? Use a new name. Don't merge anything in that branch. Just revert the unwanted commit from that new branch.